# create guava hashmaptable from excel with apache poi

Tags: apache, apache-poi, guava

Create guava hashmaptable from excel with apache poi

I have got an Excel-sheet which is built up like that:

```
SiO2    pyrite    0

SiO2   siderite   57

SiO2   plag50     53

Al2O3  pyrite     0

Al2O3  siderite   32
```

etc…
they are around 400 entries.

I want now to transfer this Excel-sheet (2013) with Apache POI (XSSF) to a guava `hashmaptable<String, String, Integer>`

```
Table <String, String, Integer> mins = HashBasedTable.create();
mins.put(“SiO2”, “siderite”, 57)
```

etc.

How to do that ? And how to transfer a hashmaptable like that back to an excel sheet ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I forgot to mention, programming language is Java

Comment: Please look at the documentation first, especially http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html which will provide many pieces that you are trying to do and then ask specific questions instead of such a broad one.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Table<String, String, Integer> table;
try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xlsx"))) {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("SheetName");
    table = HashBasedTable.create(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(), 3);
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        String rowKey = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String columnKey = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        int value = (int) row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
        table.put(rowKey, columnKey, value);
    }
}
try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SheetName");
    int physicalNumberOfRows = 0;
    for (Table.Cell<String, String, Integer> cell : table.cellSet()) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(physicalNumberOfRows++);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(cell.getRowKey());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(cell.getColumnKey());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(Objects.requireNonNull(cell.getValue()));
    }
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx")) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: An additional problem arises: After creating and filling hasmaptable "table" I want to get the value to a key:   for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> oxSumMap : table.entrySet())
   {
    System.out.println("in for-loop for oxsummap");
  "+oxSumMap.getKey());
    System.out.println("value:      "+oxSumMap.getValue());
   
    if (oxSumMap.getKey() =="SiO2")
    {
     System.out.println("in sio2-if");} It does not go into the if-clause..(????)) It seems to be so easy... also "toString" does not work...

Comment: @daejon you are using `==`, not `equals()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java for a refresher (it never hurts to review the fundamentals of a language, we all benefit from some repetition).